# Filter out all lists of a dictionary based on a condition applied to one of the lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
d={'names': ['Mark', 'Amir', 'Matt', 'Greg', 'Owen', 'Juan'], 'weight': [165, 189,
 220, 141, 260, 174], 'height': [66, 71, 72, 68, 58, 62]}
```

And I want to filter out all its lists so that they contain only the items that correspond to a height of greater than 70.

I know how to filter lists individually. For instance, the height list:

```
d["height"]=[height for height in d["height"] if height>70]
```

And that will return the dictionary with the height list filtered out:

```
{'names': ['Mark', 'Amir', 'Matt', 'Greg', 'Owen', 'Juan'], 'weight': [165, 189,
 220, 141, 260, 174], 'height': [71, 72]}
```

However, that's not what I want. What I want is:

```
{'names': ['Amir', 'Matt'], 'weight': [189,220], 'height': [71, 72]}
```

Anyone can think of how to do this?

Comment: Aside: your data would be much easier to work with in this way if you kept each person's information together, i.e. if you used a list of dictionaries like `[{'height': 66, 'name': 'Mark', 'weight': 165},
 {'height': 71, 'name': 'Amir', 'weight': 189}, etc.]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension.

```
d = {
    'names': ['Mark', 'Amir', 'Matt', 'Greg', 'Owen', 'Juan'],
    'weight': [165, 189, 220, 141, 260, 174],
    'height': [66, 71, 72, 68, 58, 62]
}

filtered_dict = {
    key: [value for i, value in enumerate(d[key]) if d['height'][i] > 70]
    for key in d
}
print filtered_dict  # {'names': ['Amir', 'Matt'], 'weight': [189, 220], 'height': [71, 72]}
```